# Uniform cell length with centered text in a table where L is the line width, K is the number of cells, and each cell is L/K long

Tags: tables, cell, textwidth

I'm trying to recreate this table. I would brute force the width with `p{kcm}` where *k* is just some number. But the text is not centered. I have tried many other solutions. But none of the work. And even if they did, there is no guarantee I can add the color. I just want, even for the future, to take the line width ***L*** and divide that by ***k*** cells so the each cells has a uniform length of ***L/k***. And I don't want the solution to do something stupid if it is in an `itemize` environment. IF there was as way to manually do it with something similar to `p{kcm}` and have the text **centered**, THEN I wouldn't mind that either

[image]
One attempt I made was using a a solution I found on stackexchange

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}

First version: Many vertical lines, 
widths of horizontal lines all equal, 
spacing above\slash below horizontal 
lines cramped

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |c| *{6}{Y|} }
\cline{2-7}
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} 
 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Fantastical aardvarks}  
 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Spelunking elephants}\\
\hline
 Foo bar & A & B & C & A & B & C\\
\hline
 5  & 87 &  5 &  2 & 82 & 18 & 48\\
 6  &  5 & 43 &  4 &  7 & 47 &  4\\
 7  &  7 & 18 & 63 &  2 &  9 & 99\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
```

But I couldn't get it to work.
This one came very close

```
\begin{table}[htb]
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{ l | l | l}
     ...&...&...
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}
```

But it makes the cell too tall

Comment: Please show us what you try so far. It seems that your intention can be easy achieved by use of the `tabularx` (or other with similar features) package. where you only need to define new columns type for text centering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With use of the `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|C|C|C|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{green!30}
$(hh)$  &   $(ht)$  &   $(tt)$                  \\
    \hline       
7 double headed coins
        &   2 regular coins
                    &   1 double headed coins   \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray} % tested with version 2021P

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = *{3}{X[c]},
                 hlines, vlines,
                 row{1} = {bg=green9, mode=math}
                }
(hh)    &   (ht)    &   (tt)                    \\       
7 double headed coins
        &   2 regular coins
                    &   1 double headed coins   \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I also put in ```[h]``` to freeze the table on the page where I put it ```\begin{table}[h]```.  How could I have gotten this off of stackexchange without asking a question. I looked for 2 days!!

Comment: @TheGreatJRB, any start is hard ... It may help you to read some introductory text about LaTeX, for example https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf. BTW, never use only `[h]` float placement specifier, this can make problems with tables (as well figures) placement. Extend them at least to `[ht]` ("here" or on the "top" of the next page, if there is not enough space for table/figure).

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[c]X[c]X[c]}[colortbl-like,hvlines]
\rowcolor{green!30}
$(hh)$  &   $(ht)$  &   $(tt)$                  \\
7 double headed coins
        &   2 regular coins
                    &   1 double headed coins   \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]